# How do native people express when they want to give a bath or hand wash, etc to their toddlers or babies?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Normally, toddlers or babies can't take a bath or wash their hands by themselves. That is their parents who do these for them.

In the dictionary

> **[have something done](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1?q=have)** (used with a past participle) to cause something to be done for you by somebody else
>
> *You've had your hair cut!*
>
> *We're having our car repaired.*

So, am I wrong  when I say these to my 2 year-old son

Hey Jonny, **let's go wash your hands**, **let's go take a bath**, **let's go wash your ass**, etc. (Note: I will do these for him, he can't do them by himself.)

What do native people say? Do they say like these?:

**let's go have your hands washed**

**let's go have you taken a bath** or **let's go have you bathed**

**let's go have your ass washed**

Comment: Just FYI, you probably wouldn't say "ass" to your little child, as it's kind of rude/vulgar, unless you _want_ to talk that way. You're likely to say something else, like _bottom_, _backside_, etc.

Comment: You _have your hair cut_, but the hairdresser cuts it. If you said "Let's go and have your hands washed", it would imply that you were taking the child to be washed by someone else, not you.

Answer (score 1):

He's just 2 and, therefore, you don't use an offensive word. Said that *bottom or back* is okay.

He's just 2. *Let's [do something]...* works **in most of the cases.** It's a way of telling babies that *we'll do...'* or *'let's do...'* because you are assisting them.

So, all your expressions - *"Johny, let's [do something]..."* are widely accepted.

Or more affectionately,

> *Johny...mama will give you a bath...*

Nevertheless, if you are telling this routine to someone then ...

> *".... and at sharp 8, I **give Johny (him) a bath.**"*

wherein you give a bath to the baby.

Different activities take different verbs. Say,

> I'll *make you sleep* 
>  *Let me wash* your hands

Comment: American films say "ass" all the time, like "Move your ass"...

Answer (score 0):

> let's go have your <s>ass</s> washed

Oh, No! This is not normal.

Here are some options; obviously, there are many other ways to say these.

You could say

> "C'mon buddy, let's get you cleaned up" [you can switch 'buddy' with 'sweety' or 'honey']

or

> "Let's go get your back cleaned, okay buddy?" [or you could use the words Em suggested]

You could say

> "It's time for shower, [enter name, nickname]"

or

> "Let's go take a bath" (as you suggest), "Time to take a bath [insert], c'mon dear", or "We are gonna go take a shower now, okay"

Answer (score 0):

You can say "Let's go take a bath".  None of the other grammar formations will ever be said.  "Taken" is literally incorrect because "taken" is last tense, and it also does not fit into this semtemce for other reasons (which are unknown).  The others are not quite literally incorrect, but anyone who has no idea about grammar or who is 5 years old, etc, would aay that they are literally incorrect, because they are just far "out there" in regards to being strange.

You also would never say "ass," because anyone who ever says "wash your ass" for any reason is not somebody that anyone else wants to speak to or listen to for one second or longer during their life...

Actually that applies to anything that you may believe is a common phrase, which states "[verb] your ass".  These are NOT common phrases and are used solely by a particular group of uneducated, violent, morons.

This does not apply to the word "ass" generally, which is merely a swear word that means butt and is therefore in way "vulgur" etc.  It is instead the particular "casual phrase" of "[verb] your ass", which will make every nonviolent American immediately and heavily dislike you if you say it.